# Remove item entities in Single Player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I accidentally loaded a string duper within lazy chunks and it caused 8000+ entities to render without being able to despawn. I'm trying to find a way to remove the items on the ground, however NBTexplorer hasn't been helpful since I'm playing BnC Advancement pack through the Curse Forge Launcher. I can still enter the world but loading the chunks crashes every time.

Comment: **This is not a request for *technical* support.** The problem is a large amount of entities (not a technical problem) of which the OP wants to get rid, and every solution would be helpful.

Comment: I disagree - surely using NBTexplorer to modify the world or a crash is a classic technical support issue.

Answer (score 2):

##### First, make sure to back up your world before trying anything, in case you get stuck in a situation where you are unable to recover.

You could enable cheats (via NBTExplorer if you don't already have them enabled), give yourself a repeating command block and place it close to the item pile (without loading it in) and add this command to the command block:

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:string"}}]
```

If you were duping a type of modded string, you want to replace the `id` property (`"minecraft:string"`) with the type of string you are trying to clear. If it was multiple types, you can either use multiple command blocks or remove the NBT argument and hope for the best. **Make sure to activate the command blocks!**

You can then load the chunks (facing away from them if that helps) and hope the command blocks are able to resolve the situation.

Once you've cleared all of the entities, destroy the command blocks and use NBTExplorer to disable cheats if you didn't have them enabled before. It might also be wise to disable the source of the problem.

Comment: And *before* anyone points out that they can't use NBTExplorer to fix the problem, please note that I am saying to modify level data and not chunk data, which is what OP tried to do.

Comment: How can /kill possibly affect entities in unloaded chunks? Surely if the entities are loaded enough to be killed they are loaded enough to crash the game.

Comment: @pppery I don't know if the game is straight-up crashing or simply freezing. If it's actually crashing I'd need a crash report.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cheats enabled, go to the chat & type `/kill @e[type=! player]`, which will kill all entities except players.

Comment: Although that is a decent answer, this person might not have cheats enabled.

Comment: Also I don't think kill affects entities in unloaded chunks anyway.